# Text not displaying on screen

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot get the entire text to display on screen.

My code is:

```
akiss =("Romeo.txt")
numwords = 0
numchars = 0

with open(akiss, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        wordslist = line.split()
        numwords += len(wordslist)
        numchars += len(line)

print (" number of words are:")
print (numwords)
print ("number of characters are:")
print (numchars)
```

Comment: You should provide more detail on what you're trying to accomplish. You say you can't get the entire text to display, but this code doesn't appear to do that.

Comment: What are you asking? What is the text you want to write to the screen? If it is the contents of the file you are reading then add a line `print(line)` directly under `numchars += len(line)`. But since what you want is completely incomprehensible my guess as to an answer is little more than random guessing. What is your question?